# How to disable Meta-Cursor Shortcuds in markdown-mode?

Tags: emacs, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts, dot-emacs

I switch windows with `M-left` and `M-right`. Also `Tab`, `S-Tab` and `C-Tab` are hardwired into my spine. Since I use `markdown-mode` my workspeed has halved.

How do I disable that `markdown-mode` re-assigns those keys on loading. The keys I describe are carefully handcrafted shortcuts from my `.emacs` file, set via `global-set-key`.

```
(global-set-key [S-iso-lefttab]  'dabbrev-expand)
(global-set-key [C-tab]  'ispell-word)
(global-set-key [M-up]     'windmove-up)
(global-set-key [M-down]   'windmove-down)
(global-set-key [M-left]  'windmove-left)
(global-set-key [M-right]  'windmove-right)
```

Comment: @Drew thanks. that works. Care to make an answer of it -- for me to accept?

Comment: Done.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set those keys also in markdown-mode, in its keymap (probably `markdown-mode-map`).  For example:

```
(define-key markdown-mode-map [C-tab] 'ispell-word)
```

The problem you saw comes from the fact that a local binding overrides a global one.  See the Elisp manual, node [Active Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html).